# .htaccess - permissions forbidden

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, .htaccess

I have an error with a new virtual host that I can't figure out.. My .htaccess doesn't have web access (403).

> [Thu Oct 31 17:51:01 2013] [crit] [client ] (13)Permission denied: /srv/data_disk/www
>   /site.dev/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check
>    htaccess file, ensure it is readable

I have set the permissions for the complete htdocs folder to 755, and to owned by my regular user and group (www-data). I have other vhosts set up with the same user and lesser permissions (rw-rw---) on the .htaccess. The virtual hosts are also setup in the same way.. as far a I can tell..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have set the permissions for the complete htdocs folder to 755

There is no htdocs directory mentioned in the error message.

Check that each element of the path

```
/srv/
/srv/data_disk
/srv/data_disk/site.dev
```

has suitable permissions to allow www-data to read and execute.

Check that the .htaccess file has suitable permissions to allow www-data to read it.

If your OS is Linux and it has SELinux enabled ensure that /srv/data_disk and the files below are suitably labelled and if not make it so.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/srv/data_disk(/.*)?"
restorecon -r /srv/data_disk
```